# Can search engines crawlers read and index SPA's virtual routes?

Tags: web-crawler, single-page-application

Frameworks like React or Vue make use of DOM manipulation for rendering components dynamically withing index.html. Additionally, SPA routers generate virtual routes (usually prefixed with "#") simulating the legacy SSR pages architecture.

Now the question is, can crawlers read within the SPA javascript links to these virtual routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a lot of blog content around this, but i think generally speaking the answer is no, google does not index hash urls e.g [www.mydomain.com/#some-route](http://www.mydomain.com/#some-route)

The question is though, why are you using a SPA for searchable content? Most use cases are for actual applications with transactional data related to the user - no need to index this.

If your site is for marketing purposes, much easier to steer away from SPAs. You can however, still use your favourite frontend framework (vue, react) with the many SSR (server side rendering) frameworks out there.

Im only familiar with Vue, and you can use Nuxt for SSR.

Also have a search around the various JAMstacks for static site generators or other SSR frameworks that use your preferred front end framework.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I am already using Nuxt for the very same reasons you exposed. I just wanted to know more about SEO and crawlers limitations.